# Boost Graph find neighbours of a group of vertices

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I have an `undirected_unweighted_graph graph;` which is defined as follows:

```
typedef typename boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS,boost::vecS,boost::undirectedS,boost::no_property,boost::no_property> undirected_unweighted_graph;
```

It has several vertices which are interconnected by undirected edges.
During my algorithm, I'm searching for a connected subgraph of `graph` which only contains some of the vertices, which has certain properties.

I'm using a linear optimization software package which provides me with possible optimal solutions for my problem. A solution consists of a set of vertices with a fixed size n and might be infeasible (i.e. the vertices are not connected in the corresponding subgraph of `graph`). I'm currently generating a new graph with the vertices of the solution and adding the edges which are also present in `graph`. I'm using `boost::connected_components()` to calculate the connected components for it.

Now I come to my question:
The next step for me is to improve the performance of generating a solution by imposing a constraint. Specifically, I will "grow" a solution, starting from a single node and ending with a subgraph of `n` nodes. At each stage, a partial solution will grow by adding one of its neighbors. *(The idea is that if a partial solution can grow to a full solution, then at least one of its neighbors will be in the full solution.)* How can I identify these neighbors?

My approach is the following:

I'm iterating over each component and then iterate over `boost::out_edges(v, g)`. I then have to check if the neighbor is part of my component or not. If it is not part of the component I add it to the component neighbor group. I wonder if there is any way in boost to iterate over `boost::out_edges(V, g)` for a list of vertices `V`.

**EDIT**

To be more concrete: Given a graph, I am able to iterate over the neighbors of a given vertex like this:

```
for (auto edge: boost::make_iterator_range(boost::out_edges(v, graph))) {
    //do stuff
}
```

What if I have a connected component, say a vector of vertices `std::vector<size_t> component`. What I want are the outgoing edges of the component meaning all outgoing edges of the vertices excluding those which are between two vertices of `component`. Is there an elegant way to get those edges efficiently?

Comment: FWIW, your question is a bit broad. Consider restricting your question to be more concrete.

Comment: I did not notice this. I updated my question.

Comment: I'm confused by _"If a certain subgraph is part of the solution at least one of its neighbors has to be part of the solution too."_ This seems impossible, unless you mean "proper subgraph" and the solution consists of all vertices. _Why:_ The solution consists of a set of vertices. These vertices form a subgraph, so at least one of this subgraph's neighbors (not in the subgraph, hence not in the solution) has to be part of the solution? The neighbor is simultaneously not in the solution and in the solution -- contradiction.

Comment: A solution has a fixed size n. This statement only holds for subgraphs that have <n vertices. Therefore, for any of those subgraphs I need one neighbor vertex to be part of the solution, too. I‘m sorry for the misleading statement.

Comment: @michip96 Sorry, I had not noticed you replied since you did not tag me in your reply. I still don't understand what you are trying to do. You get a solution of size `n`, which you use to generate a new graph based on the original graph. To detect "infeasible" you use `boost::connected_components()` to make sure the new graph is connected (i.e. has a single connected component). The next step is to take a proper subgraph of your solution and make sure it has a neighbor that is part of the solution? But that is guaranteed by having only one connected component, so why do this test?

Comment: @JaMiT Sorry for not tagging you. Yes, I can detect an infeasible solution by just counting the connected components. I want to do this test because it gives me the opportunity to help the linear optimization software (i.e. by adding additional constraints to the linear program). When it knows which vertices it needs to add in order to keep a certain subgraph as a part of the solution, the solving process can be accelerated a lot. This is similar to adding proper "subtour constraints" in problems like TSP.  Even tho I have a specific problem the question can be seen much broader (see my edit).

Comment: @michip96 Well, yes, if we assume your approach is a good one, then your specific question becomes that broader one with a quick and negative answer. However, I don't like that assumption. I think I understand your scenario well enough to clarify your question. If I miss the mark, feel free to revert my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I would not iterate over multiple vertices. Instead, I would maintain two sets of vertices – one containing the vertices in the current partial solution, and one containing the vertices adjacent to (and not in) the partial solution. When the linear optimization package adds a vertex to the partial solution, that vertex should also be moved from the set of adjacencies to the set of vertices in the solution. Next the edges coming from the new vertex need to be iterated over, but only those from the new vertex. For each vertex adjacent to the new one, if it is not in the partial solution then add it to the set of adjacent vertices.

I would also try something similar using just one set containing both the vertices in the partial solution and those adjacent to the partial solution. Less overhead. Depending on what the surrounding code expects, this set might work as well as the one with just the adjacent vertices.

The advantage of this approach is that you eliminate repetitive work. If you already looked at all the neighbors of vertex A, why should you need to look at them *again* just because vertex B was added to your set?

A disadvantage of this approach is that you might require significant memory overhead if you need to backtrack at times (think depth-first search and maintaining a stack of these sets). How bad this is depends on how big `n` is and, on average, how many edges connect to each vertex. Even in a bad case, some clever elimination of redundancy might salvage this approach, but I'll leave that for later.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly the linear optimization program needs a lot of memory (i.e. it rapidly exceeds 64GB of RAM). Moreover, I can not "track" a solution through the process. Therefore, I need a way to efficiently gather the neighbors of a subset of maximum size of a given component, if present. Anyway, this surely does work for other applications than mine.